Apache Ignite: IgniteException Failed to unmarshal object with optimized marshaller
I have a .Net 8 application that uses Apache Ignite .Net v2.16. Now I'm trying to build a Java 17 app that would join the Ignite cluster of the .Net app and use the native Ignite API to programatically reset lost partitions when such a condition is detected (further described in another SO question). The Java app also uses v2.16.
When the Java app starts and Ignite initializes, I get the following error:
Jun 30, 2024 2:09:19 PM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger error
SEVERE: Failed to notify listener: o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture$4@ea22348
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to unmarshal object with optimized marshaller
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsFullMessage.partitionSizes(GridDhtPartitionsFullMessage.java:447)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.updatePartitionFullMap(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:4767)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.processFullMessage(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:4727)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.access$1500(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:162)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture$4.apply(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:4411)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture$4.apply(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:4399)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListener$$$capture(GridFutureAdapter.java:474)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListener(GridFutureAdapter.java)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.listen(GridFutureAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.onReceiveFullMessage(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:4399)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.processFullPartitionUpdate(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:1981)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$3.onMessage(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:469)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$3.onMessage(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:454)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$MessageHandler.apply(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3750)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$MessageHandler.apply(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3729)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.processMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:1164)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:605)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:406)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:324)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$100(GridCacheIoManager.java:112)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$1.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:314)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1906)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1527)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$5300(GridIoManager.java:242)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.execute(GridIoManager.java:1420)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:55)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to unmarshal object with optimized marshaller
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshalZip(IgniteUtils.java:10836)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsFullMessage.partitionSizes(GridDhtPartitionsFullMessage.java:443)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to unmarshal object with optimized marshaller
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadOptimized(BinaryUtils.java:1849)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1974)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1731)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadObject(BinaryUtils.java:1862)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.deserializeOrUnmarshal(BinaryUtils.java:2286)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadMap(BinaryUtils.java:2270)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1936)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1731)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.GridBinaryMarshaller.deserialize(GridBinaryMarshaller.java:322)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.GridBinaryMarshaller.deserialize(GridBinaryMarshaller.java:307)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryMarshaller.unmarshal0(BinaryMarshaller.java:120)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:92)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshalZip(IgniteUtils.java:10830)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to deserialize object with given class loader: [clsLdr=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheDeploymentManager$CacheClassLoader@158d255c, err=Unable to make field private static final long java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.serialVersionUID accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @1996cd68]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller.unmarshal0(OptimizedMarshaller.java:261)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller.unmarshal0(OptimizedMarshaller.java:225)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:92)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadOptimized(BinaryUtils.java:1846)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private static final long java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.serialVersionUID accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @1996cd68
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshallerUtils.computeSerialVersionUid(OptimizedMarshallerUtils.java:365)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedClassDescriptor.<init>(OptimizedClassDescriptor.java:621)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedClassDescriptor.<init>(OptimizedClassDescriptor.java:201)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshallerUtils.descriptorFromCache(OptimizedMarshallerUtils.java:338)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshallerUtils.classDescriptor(OptimizedMarshallerUtils.java:273)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readObject0(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readObjectOverride(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:205)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:467)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller.unmarshal0(OptimizedMarshaller.java:251)
    ... 44 more

Jun 30, 2024 2:09:19 PM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger error
SEVERE: Failed processing message [senderId=7c4fa358-81d5-4f10-a484-addac9cc75fb, msg=GridDhtPartitionsFullMessage [parts=HashMap {-2100569601=GridDhtPartitionFullMap {7c4fa358-81d5-4f10-a484-addac9cc75fb=GridDhtPartitionMap [moving=0, top=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=0], updateSeq=2, size=100]}}, partCntrs=IgniteDhtPartitionCountersMap [], partCntrs2=o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.IgniteDhtPartitionCountersMap2@3b62a8d6, partHistSuppliers=IgniteDhtPartitionHistorySuppliersMap [], partsToReload=IgniteDhtPartitionsToReloadMap [], topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], errs=HashMap {}, resTopVer=null, flags=1, partCnt=1, super=GridDhtPartitionsAbstractMessage [exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=null, nodeId=99abc230, evt=NODE_JOINED], lastVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=0, order=1719749325195, nodeOrder=0, dataCenterId=0], super=GridCacheMessage [msgId=1, depInfo=null, lastAffChangedTopVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=0], err=null, skipPrepare=false]]]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to unmarshal object with optimized marshaller
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsFullMessage.partitionSizes(GridDhtPartitionsFullMessage.java:447)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.updatePartitionFullMap(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:4767)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.processFullMessage(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:4727)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.access$1500(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:162)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture$4.apply(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:4411)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture$4.apply(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:4399)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListener$$$capture(GridFutureAdapter.java:474)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListener(GridFutureAdapter.java)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.listen(GridFutureAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.onReceiveFullMessage(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:4399)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.processFullPartitionUpdate(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:1981)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$3.onMessage(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:469)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$3.onMessage(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:454)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$MessageHandler.apply(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3750)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$MessageHandler.apply(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3729)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.processMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:1164)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:605)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:406)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:324)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$100(GridCacheIoManager.java:112)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$1.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:314)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1906)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1527)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$5300(GridIoManager.java:242)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.execute(GridIoManager.java:1420)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:55)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to unmarshal object with optimized marshaller
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshalZip(IgniteUtils.java:10836)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsFullMessage.partitionSizes(GridDhtPartitionsFullMessage.java:443)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to unmarshal object with optimized marshaller
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadOptimized(BinaryUtils.java:1849)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1974)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1731)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadObject(BinaryUtils.java:1862)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.deserializeOrUnmarshal(BinaryUtils.java:2286)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadMap(BinaryUtils.java:2270)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1936)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1731)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.GridBinaryMarshaller.deserialize(GridBinaryMarshaller.java:322)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.GridBinaryMarshaller.deserialize(GridBinaryMarshaller.java:307)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryMarshaller.unmarshal0(BinaryMarshaller.java:120)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:92)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshalZip(IgniteUtils.java:10830)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to deserialize object with given class loader: [clsLdr=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheDeploymentManager$CacheClassLoader@158d255c, err=Unable to make field private static final long java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.serialVersionUID accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @1996cd68]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller.unmarshal0(OptimizedMarshaller.java:261)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller.unmarshal0(OptimizedMarshaller.java:225)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:92)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadOptimized(BinaryUtils.java:1846)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private static final long java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.serialVersionUID accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @1996cd68
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshallerUtils.computeSerialVersionUid(OptimizedMarshallerUtils.java:365)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedClassDescriptor.<init>(OptimizedClassDescriptor.java:621)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedClassDescriptor.<init>(OptimizedClassDescriptor.java:201)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshallerUtils.descriptorFromCache(OptimizedMarshallerUtils.java:338)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshallerUtils.classDescriptor(OptimizedMarshallerUtils.java:273)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readObject0(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readObjectOverride(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:205)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:467)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller.unmarshal0(OptimizedMarshaller.java:251)
    ... 44 more

Jun 30, 2024 2:09:19 PM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger error
SEVERE: Critical system error detected. Will be handled accordingly to configured handler [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=CRITICAL_ERROR, err=class o.a.i.IgniteException: Failed to unmarshal object with optimized marshaller]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to unmarshal object with optimized marshaller
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsFullMessage.partitionSizes(GridDhtPartitionsFullMessage.java:447)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.updatePartitionFullMap(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:4767)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.processFullMessage(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:4727)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.access$1500(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:162)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture$4.apply(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:4411)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture$4.apply(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:4399)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListener$$$capture(GridFutureAdapter.java:474)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListener(GridFutureAdapter.java)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.listen(GridFutureAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.onReceiveFullMessage(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:4399)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.processFullPartitionUpdate(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:1981)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$3.onMessage(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:469)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$3.onMessage(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:454)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$MessageHandler.apply(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3750)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$MessageHandler.apply(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3729)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.processMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:1164)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:605)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:406)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:324)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$100(GridCacheIoManager.java:112)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$1.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:314)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1906)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1527)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$5300(GridIoManager.java:242)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.execute(GridIoManager.java:1420)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:55)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to unmarshal object with optimized marshaller
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshalZip(IgniteUtils.java:10836)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsFullMessage.partitionSizes(GridDhtPartitionsFullMessage.java:443)
    ... 28 more

I learned that the optimized marshaller isn't used in .Net version and attempted to force the Binary one by adding the following code to the Java app but it didn't help.
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
BinaryMarshaller marshaller = new BinaryMarshaller();
cfg.setMarshaller(marshaller);

Am I missing anything?


build a Java 17 app that would join the Ignite cluster of the .Net app and use the native Ignite API to programatically reset lost partitions

Not sure about the error you get, but I would recommend a different overall approach:

Implement the logic to reset lost partitions in Java as a ComputeTask
Add the resulting class/jar file to classpath
Use ICompute.ExecuteJavaTask method to call the task from .NET

This way you don't need separate Java-only nodes in the cluster, which makes the approach simpler and more robust.
